# ColdFusion send mail resource not found

Tags: email, coldfusion

I am sending mails in coldfusion as below. But some of my emails being sent are thrown out with the exception below:

```
<cfif !IsNull(SignatureDetails) && len(trim(SignatureDetails.getDigitalSignature()))>
    <!--- Embed digital signature if present via the local file system. --->
    <cfset variables.signatureUrl = '../../../urls/files/messages/spreadsheet/rows/columns/' & #SignatureDetails.getDigitalSignature()#>
    <cfmailparam file="#ExpandPath('#variables.signatureUrl#')#" contentid="digitalSignature" disposition="inline"/>
</cfif>
```

And the exception:

```
object.email.sendTemplateEmail: The resource C:\Data\map\urls\files\messages\spreadsheet\rows\columns\column.jpg was not found. The root cause was: ''.
```

The correct path should be: C:\Data\urls\files\messages\spreadsheet\rows\columns\column.jpg

The issue is that it is only happening on a select few emails being sent. The directory is hardcoded as above while the name of the signature is pulled from a table in my db.

Comment: it is possible that the file name which exists in your DB, does not have the file physically on the server.

Comment: Another thing which could go wrong is how the files in that directory are uploaded. If the upload code has a bug, it is possible that say you are uploading the file xyz.jpg, and storing the same name in DB, but as xyz.jpg already exists, it is renamed. Though in such case it will be some other file will be added instead of intended one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the use of relative pathing in this line

```
<cfset variables.signatureUrl = '../../../urls/files/messages/spreadsheet/rows/columns/' & #SignatureDetails.getDigitalSignature()#>
```

It is possible that the code is being run from a slightly different directory path depending on the page being executed, as such, going up 3 directories may not give you the path you are looking for. When ColdFusion cannot find a path as you have defined, it appends the know path to the end of the path in which the file being processed exists.

You can correct this by creating a mapping to the signatures (or attachments directory) directory (you define the mapping in Application.cfc) and using this to add the signature.

For mapping pointing to 'signatures' and named 'signatures'

```
<cfset variables.signatureUrl = '/columns/' & SignatureDetails.getDigitalSignature()>
```

For mapping pointing to 'attachments' and named 'attachments'

```
<cfset variables.signatureUrl = '/rows/columns/' & SignatureDetails.getDigitalSignature()>
```

If you need information about creating mappings in Application.cfc, please check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appFramework_04.html).

Comment: I'm with Scott... it looks like your relative path needs one more "../" in it to get past the /sites/ folder.  I would an absolute path instead. Set a mapping as Scot suggested - or even an application variable.

Comment: Yeah, i investigated his suggestion and it is the culprit, to fix this i've changed to to the absolute path. Thanks for your help

Comment: Be careful with absolute paths. When you move this code to the server (you are coding locally, right?) the paths need to match. If you use a mapping in Application.cfc, you need not worry about where the application resides on the server, but with absolute pathing, you do.